# SSL Cipher help in C

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, https, rsa

I am trying to Use SSL on top of tcp/ip to send an HTTPS request to a site using C. I have no access to curl or other standard libraries. Pretend like i can't load any libraries at all.

I need to set an SSL Profile Cipher. When I successfully use curl on my linux box to talk with the server I see: `SSL Connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA`

If my options for setting the cipher are:

- SSL_kRSA (RSA Key Exchange)
- SSL_kEDH (tmp DH key no DH cert)
- SSL_aRSA (Authenticate with RSA)
- SSL-aDSS (Authenticate with DSS)
- SSL_DES (DES)
- SSL_3DES (3DES)
- SSL_RC4 (RC4)
- SSL_RC2 (RC2)
- SSL_AES (AES)
- SSL_MD5 (MD5)
- SSL_SHA1 (SHA1)
- SSL_SHA256 (SHA256)
- SSL_SHA384 (SHA384)
- SSL_RSA ([SSL_kRSA|SSL_aRSA] RSA)
- SSL_DSS ([SSL_aDSS] Authenticate with DSS)

I can set multiple things by something like:
`SSL_RSA | SSL_AES`

Protocol is TLSv1.2

What should my cipher look like?

Comment: SSL_RSA | SSL_AES might actually be the correct cipher after all?

Comment: Please don't try to write your own SSL/TLS implementation. There are hundreds of pitfalls which will make your implementation insecure or even dangerously for your application. Use one of the common libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pretend like i can't load any libraries at all." If that is true, you will need to implement the cipher itself plus the SSL handling layer ^_^.

Assuming you are using OpenSSL and have TCP established with socket_fd, you need to create a SSL_CTX with `SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_client_method())`. Normally, to set the cipher list, you use `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:@STRENGTH")`, see http://openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html for all available options, you may specific a particular cipher.

Then create a SSL session with `SSL_new(ctx)` and `SSL_set_fd (ssl, socket_fd)`, after that use `SSL_connect(...)`, `SSL_read(...)/SSL_write(...)` to communicate with server.

After all have been done, `SSL_shutdown(...)` and `SSL_Free(...)`, `SSL_CTX_Free(...)`.